# Invalid QR Code WalletConnect v2.0 Android

Tags: android, wallet, wallet-connect, web3modal

I have developed a simple online application under an https domain allowing a user to connect with WalletConnect using its version 2 with the [standalone configuration](https://docs.walletconnect.com/2.0/web3modal/standalone/installation).

When I try my application on desktop I have the modal that appears correctly. I can then scan the QR code with an **Android** or **iOS** phone and connect with [a wallet compatible with V2](https://explorer.walletconnect.com/?type=wallet&version=2) (I use **Spot**)

When I try my app from a browser on **iOS** and **iPadOS**, I can select my wallet, I am redirected correctly and I can connect correctly.

However, when I try the same manipulation from a browser on **Android**, I can select my wallet, I am redirected properly BUT I get an error message telling me:

> Invalid QR Code WalletConnect

I tested this with several Android phones and tablets, with several browsers, but I get the same error every time.

[image]

Is there an explanation for this behavior? Knowing that the v2 of walletconnect is from what I understand [still in migration](https://docs.walletconnect.com/2.0/web3modal/about#versioning).

Note that I have the same behavior on the Walletconnect examples on this page: https://lab.web3modal.com/ for version 2 but not for version 1.

Comment: There is a new update of Spot available in the Store that should fix your issue. Let me know if it's fine!
Cyril, Spot Android developer

Answer (score 0):

Lead android dev from Spot here. Thanks for reporting, this bug has already been fixed this week and will be included in the next update of Spot Android, which should be available on Monday.

I will ping you back when it's available to download to try it again with the new version :)

Cheers,

Cyril